# Using cx_oracle when muliple Oracle clients in the path

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using cx_Oracle to access the Oracle database for some time and it works fine. Now my co-worker wants to run my scripts and we run across a problem with cx_Oracle. Wile trying to connect to the database we got the error: InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle. 
I read on a stackoverflow post that the probable error is that there are multiple oci.dll files found on the path. In our case we have two instant clients installed,I installed instant client 12 and there is another, very old installed from before that is used by some other applications. How can I tell Python which instant client to use?

She is using Windows XP and I installed her instant client 12, python 3.4 and cx_oracle 5.2, all 32 bit.

Comment: You should try improving the formatting in the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the `PATH` and `ORACLE_HOME` environment variables are pointing to the same Oracle client install.  In the case of `PATH` (which you imply may contain multiple Oracle client installations), you need to ensure the one you wish to use appears first.

Instead of relying on system-wide settings for these environment variables, you may want to wrap your Python script in a batch file that ensures these variables are set correctly before starting the interpreter.  For example, assuming you installed the Oracle 12.1 instant client to `C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_1`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ORACLE_HOME=C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_1
SET PATH=C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_1;%PATH%
python path_to_my_script.py
```